# How far can I move my bath tub trap from the vent?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

I am remodeling the master bath and I need to relocate the bath tub. I will be extending the trap about 3-4' from where it is now. I'm wondering if I need to relocate the vent pipe as well. How far can it be from the vent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the diameter of the trap.  Under International Building Code use table 906.1.

A 1.5" trap can be 6 feet from the vent (if your trap is only 1.25" the maximum distance is 5 feet).

It looks like you should be fine in your situation.